# how to find the next match while searching in chrome's developer inspector search box

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I used the search in the developer inspector window to find out on which all lines a particular text repeats. It even notifies me it has multiple matches...How do I find the next match?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Return` key will jump to the match and `shift-Return` will take you to the previous match.

Took me a while to figure it out too.

Comment: Cmd-G Cmd-Shift-G also work